# Twice the amount of drives show up when setting up a RAID array

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I am trying to set up an array, with ubuntu.

I have hooked up an array containing 12 drives of 1TB, but when I run the following command, it returns 24 - 1TB drives.

What's causing this, and where do I start?

```
sudo lshw -C disk -short

H/W path               Device       Class      Description
==========================================================
/0/100/7/0/0.0.0       /dev/sdb     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.1.0       /dev/sdc     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.2.0       /dev/sdd     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.3.0       /dev/sde     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.4.0       /dev/sdf     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.5.0       /dev/sdg     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.6.0       /dev/sdh     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.7.0       /dev/sdi     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.8.0       /dev/sdj     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.9.0       /dev/sdk     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.a.0       /dev/sdl     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.b.0       /dev/sdm     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.d.0       /dev/sdn     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.e.0       /dev/sdo     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.f.0       /dev/sdp     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.10.0      /dev/sdq     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.11.0      /dev/sdr     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.12.0      /dev/sds     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.13.0      /dev/sdt     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.14.0      /dev/sdu     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.15.0      /dev/sdv     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.16.0      /dev/sdw     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.17.0      /dev/sdx     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/7/0/0.18.0      /dev/sdy     disk       1TB SCSI Disk
/0/100/1f.1/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom   disk       DVD reader
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0      /dev/sda     disk       320GB Hitachi HDT72503
/0/1/0.0.0             /dev/cdrom1  disk       SCSI CD-ROM
```

Comment: What kind of hardware array is this and what type of drives?  Are they SATA?  SAS?  Are they in an enclosure that provides multipath connections?  You might check the drives' serial numbers in the disk utility and see if the same drive is appearing twice ( because you have two connections to it ).

Answer (score -1):

try this as root (sudo -i):

first `fdisk -l`

then `hdparm -i /dev/sd* | grep -i serial`

```
 Model=WDC WD3200BPVT-22ZEST0, FwRev=01.01A01, SerialNo=WD-WX71A61P7681
```

that's another way to know about your drives info.